# vuejs Props are readonly

Tags: vue.js

I'm new to Vue and learning Vuejs 3. I have a list of tasks. I want show that list and a span at the end of each line, so the line gets deleted by clicking on that span.

I have this code for createApp:

```
const babies = Vue.createApp({
    data(){
        return{
            tasks:[
                {id: 0,kid:'Sabina',tache:'eductate'}
                {id: 1,kid:'Henry',tache:'listen'}
           ]
        }
    },
    components:{
        'listbabies':Compodeux
    },
    methods:{
        supprimer(ido){
            this.tasks = Object.values(this.tasks).filter(item => item.id !== ido)
        }    
    }
})
```

and the component contains this:

```
const Compodeux=('listbabies',{
    props:{
        tasks:{
            type: Object
        },
        suppr:{
            type: Function
        }
    },
    data(){
        return{
            line:"line_" + this.tasks.id
        }
    },
    template:
        `<div :id=this.ligne>
            <div id="ligne_credits">
                <span> {{tasks.kid}} </span>
                <span> {{tasks.tache}} </span>
                <span  @click="$emit(this.supprimer(taches.id))" :id="taches.id"> [*] </span>
            </div>
        </div>
        `
})
```

All this code works fine, but for the `@click` in the component template. I get an error message:
`this.supprimer is not a function`

Comment: It is not recommended to modify a prop in Vue.js. You could use Event Emitting to emit a event to the parent and remove it there.

Comment: I have updated the code accordingly. Still get an error.

Comment: Please check the emit syntax again. Use [this](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-custom-events.html) as a reference.

Comment: I must be blind.... I don't see it.

Comment: Use a custom event name instead of parsing the function directly as a parameter. In the `$emit`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a custom event by defining the name in the `emit` function.

```html
@click="$emit('supprimer', taches.id)
```

And then you need to catch the event in the parent components template.

```html
<template>
  <MyChildComponent @supprimer="supprimer" />
</template>
```

For more details, check [the docs](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-custom-events.html).

Comment: I works. It's exactly the catching the event in the parent component template that I didn't understand (and don't find it clear in the docs - which is due to me).

Answer (score 0):

Try `@click="$emit("supprimer" , taches.id)"`
instead of `@click="$emit(this.supprimer(taches.id))"`

Comment: Then I get no more error messages, but nothing happens (replaced the double quotes around supprimer with single quotes)

Comment: Change supperimer body to this.tasks = this.tasks.splice(ido, 1);

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question is on the vue doc, since props update data one-way.

According to the vue doc;

*When objects and arrays are passed as props, while the child component cannot mutate the prop binding, it will be able to mutate the object or array's nested properties. This is because in JavaScript objects and arrays are passed by reference, and it is unreasonably expensive for Vue to prevent such mutations.
The main drawback of such mutations is that it allows the child component to affect parent state in a way that isn't obvious to the parent component, potentially making it more difficult to reason about the data flow in the future. As a best practice, you should avoid such mutations unless the parent and child are tightly coupled by design. In most cases, the child should emit an event to let the parent perform the mutation.*